# Bash: replace substring with empty string

Tags: string, bash, shell, replace, substring

I have folders named:

```
example1 example2 example3
```

And I want to extract the example number from each of them. Something like:

```
for exampleSubfolder in `find . -type d`
do
  example_number= #replace 'example' in $exampleSubfolder with empty string
  #do other stuff in this subfolder
done
```

Any simple way to do this?

Comment: If your folders are in the current directory, `for exampleSubfolder in example?/` avoids the `find` invocation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you only need the number:

```
find . -type d -name 'example*' | egrep -o "[0-9]+"
```

But if you want to know the correspondance between folder name and number:

```
for f in $(find . -mindepth 1 -maxdepth 1 -type d -name 'example*')
do
   number=${f#example}
done
```

Updated with the string replace bashism.

Comment: Nice, so I can do `echo $exampleSubfolder | egrep -o "[0-9]+"` and get the number

Comment: It will recurse as deep as it can instead of only the one level and is less efficient then using the bash glob, also it will match numbers along the path anywhere, not just at the end.

Comment: You can avoid the external process by doing `number=${f#example}`.

Comment: @Geoffrey: Yes, it is true if the folders are in the top level of the current directory.

Comment: @tripleee: thanks for the substring bashism (I often forgot it)

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
for DIR in /path/to/search/example*; do
  if [ ! -d $DIR ]; then continue; fi
  NUMBER=$(echo $DIR | grep -Eo '[0-9]+$')
  pushd $DIR
    # Do stuff here
  popd
done
```

Answer (score 2):

```
find . -name "example*" -type d | awk -F"example" '{print $NF}'
```